# AWS Lex - Best practises to handle unknown responses

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have developed chatbot which takes user preferences for example their destination. 
In this case I return response card asking if they want to choose any of these top 4 destination (displayed as buttons for that response card). The user can choose one of them or enter one of his own. 
The slot type for the above is configured as AWS.Country . But the issue is how to handle unknown responses such as when the user enters as "None" or "I dont know". In such cases Lex passes the exact text for the above slot to Lambda .I was presuming it should not. Anyways in order to handle such cases should we put check in lambda for such unknown expressions as the lambda needs to respond to it by asking further questions (or triggering another intent).

The only concern there is we end up hardcoding in Lambda to compare against "None ",I dnt know etc and there is no machine learning involved there.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 2):

We have to handle such special cases in lambda and there is no other way. This process is called normalisation, which, in some complex bots require a db to manage. Unfortunately, lex ML is restricted only to standard slot and standard intent improvement.

While this unknown responses are smaller problem to handle, the bigger problem arises when you do not use response cards (meaning, user can type in any input) and you need to capture that value into a slot and then take necessary action (making a service call). In this scenario, life becomes even tougher as we have to maintain a normalisation dictionary in the backend.